# How to retrieve the "show as available / busy" info of the google calendar event?

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is there a field in the Calendar.v3.Data.Event that indicates the "show as available / busy" of the calendar event? I am not able to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field is called transparency and transparent maps to available, opaque to busy.

Comment: Thanks! I get null from transparency most of the time, does that mean "busy"? I did get "transparent" for the event I set to "show as available"

Comment: Yes, busy is the default value.